# how can AWS EC2 can write 'docker-compose up' automatically Repeatedly without my control?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

my crawler work on AWS EC2. but when i want to make it run, everytime i have to run EC2, then i have to write `cd FileName` and `sudo docker-compose up -d`.

it make me so tired.

i hope something can work instead of me, after i search about `ECS`

but there is really lots of data and i can't filter what is accurate information for me.

if you don't mind can you recommend the links what i can solve this issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ECS which is available in two favors

Serverless (Fargate) where you don't have to manage anything except your docker compose file and second is to use EC2 as launch type for ECS.

Docker and AWS have been collaborating and now there is an in built support for docker compose files since . Please refer to official docs
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/
https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-for-amazon-ecs-now-available/